# Custom Javascript Not Loading On Paginated Pages (Except First Page) In Drupal

Tags: javascript, drupal, dom, pagination

I am running the following jQuery that affects elements on a page view.

```
$(document).ready(function($){                    
    $(".views-field-field-video").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().find("a.cboxElement").click();
    }); 
});
```

The code works perfectly, but only on the first page. When I use the pager at the bottom and navigate to any other page, the script does not work. Then, when I navigate back to the first page, the script also fails.

If I reload the page however, it brings me back to the first page and the script works again.

I am linking a .js file, and link in between the `<head> </head>` tags using `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://source_to_file"></script>` It is loading, I can see in the web developer tool.

EDIT: 
The classes I am selecting in the script remains the same on all pages.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are only adding click events when the page is first loaded.  If you are then dynamically adding HTML (with pagination) then you need to re-add the click events to those new objects.

Comment: Thank you, davehale23. What would be the best way to do this? Should I add this script to the affected `<divs>`?

Comment: See if your pagination widget has some sort of `onComplete` handler and then add your `$(".views-field-field-video").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().find("a.cboxElement").click();
    });` to that handler.  Without knowing which pagination widget you are using it's hard to know.  But, basically, you just want to bind that click handler to the new HTML that your pagination widget just created.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just need to reatache the event. Drupal gives you a great way to do that right in your javascript:

```
Drupal.attachBehaviors('.behavior_class');
```

This will cause a lot of headache if you don't have context passed to your behaviors though.

Make sure your code is wrapped in, for drupal 6:

```
Drupal.behaviors.clikfocus_map = function (context) {
```

for drupal 7:

```
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.ajax_example = {
    attach:function (context) {
    }
  }
})(jQuery);
```

and your selectors should all have

```
$('.myselector', context');
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to just turn off AJAX on the view. Sorry to over complicate things, but thank you for all your help!